# Linq orderby national character sets

Tags: linq, internationalization, generic-list

I have a List which i OrderBy alfabetically on a property.

Unfortunatly the database setup (i guess) does not handle national characters properly when fetching the data..I cannot change that though (not my database), so I need to solve the problem directly on this specific. I have therefore simplified the example below.

```
            var x1 = new Shop() {city = "Århus"};
            var x2 = new Shop() { city = "Ans" };
            var x3 = new Shop() { city = "Balle" };

            list.Add(x1);
            list.Add(x2);
            list.Add(x3);
            list = list.OrderBy(a => a.city).ToList();

            //Result:
            // Århus, Ans, Balle
            // Should be:
            // Ans, Balle, Århus
```

The commentes should explain my problem: The "Å" is the last letter in danish character set

I am not in control over the application settings, but can I force the OrderBy to order using a specific caracter set?

Thanks in advance,

Steen Pedersen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could specify a culture when ordering. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Set Denmark as current culture
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
        var cities = new[] { "Århus", "Ans", "Balle" };

        // When ordering the cities indicate that you want to 
        // take the current culture into account
        cities = cities.OrderBy(a => a, StringComparer.CurrentCulture).ToArray();

        foreach (var city in cities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(city);
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Ans
Balle
Århus
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Had to change object type from List<> to Array and back in order to make it work, but that was not included in the question...